# Why am I getting errors in my AD update script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script to update various AD fields (including extension attributes) from a CSV on a weekly basis.  It seems to work fine for a lot of accounts, but some get the following error and don't update:

```
Set-ADUser : replace
At C:\ADMaint\ADupdate.ps1:45 char:11
+ Set-ADUser <<<<  -EmployeeNumber $($user."employeeNumber") -Department $($user."department") -Title $($user."title") -Office $($user."physicalDeliveryOfficeName") -StreetAddress $($user."streetAddress") -City $($user."l") -State $($user ."st") -PostalCode $($user."postalCode") -Company $($user."Company") -Officephone $($user."telephoneNumber") -Mobile $( $user."mobile") -Fax $($user."facsimileTelephoneNumber")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=Name\, Name...C=domain,DC=com:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

This is the script:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\ADMaint\ADUpdate.csv
# Loop through CSV and update users if the exist in CVS file

foreach ($user in $users) {
  #Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes
  Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.employeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
    Set-ADUser -EmployeeNumber $($user."employeeNumber") -Department $($user."department") -Title $($user."title") -Office $($user."physicalDeliveryOfficeName") -StreetAddress $($user."streetAddress") -City $($user."l") -State $($user."st") -PostalCode $($user."postalCode") -Company $($user."Company") -Officephone $($user."telephoneNumber") -Mobile $($user."mobile") -Fax $($user."facsimileTelephoneNumber")
  Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.employeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute1=($user.extensionAttribute1); ExtensionAttribute2=($user.extensionAttribute2); ExtensionAttribute3=($user.extensionAttribute3); ExtensionAttribute4=($user.extensionAttribute4)}
}
```

Comment: This can happen because of empty fields in your CSV : this results in trying to feed an empty value for a parameter.

Comment: If this is the reason then I think you can workaround it by surrounding your sub expressions with double quotes, so that if they become empty strings instead of $null

Comment: I think that is the issue after all.  Where should I place the double quotes to get by this problem?